# Definition of Inverse of Unbounded Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, unbounded-operators

I am currently studying unbounded operators. However, in the text I am using, the definition for the inverse of an unbounded operator is given. I also went to several other books I own and the definition is not given either. I am inquiring if anyone has a concise definition for a densely defined unbounded operator on a Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's more or less exactly what it has to be:

> If $T:H_1\rightarrow H_2$ has range $\mathcal{R}(T)$ and is injective on its domain $\mathcal{D}(T),$ then we can define the inverse $T^{-1}: H_2\rightarrow H_1$, with domain $\mathcal{D}(T^{-1})=\mathcal{R}(T).$